# Edit bootable img file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu, unix, img

I have downloaded a [bootable image of Ubuntu](http://downloads.parallella.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/image/ubuntu-14.04-140611.img.gz) (7.95Gb .img file) for a Parallella (minicomputer), but its too big to fit on my 8GB micro sd card (which actually is only 7.8 GB!).

I would like to remove some software from this image like Libre Office. However when I mount the image on a mac the folder appears to be empty. Except for a few hidden folders (`.Trashes`, `._.Trashes`, `.fseventsd`) there is nothing.

Is there a way to remove some of the content of this `.img`?

Comment: This really is the hard way to do it. The image was never meant to be edited and could leave some nasty bugs, not to mention that it's a lot of effort.  Do you need the larger ubuntu ISO or could you get a smaller one, install it, uninstall stuff from within ubuntu, and maybe then install extra features you need?

Comment: Edit:  (sorry, on my phone)  im not familiar with Parallella, but a minimum image size of 7.95gb seems really high.  Do they not have any stripped down versions you can download?  For instance, maybe one with with XFCE instead of GNOME, or even better, no desktop enviroment at all?  If you could get one with no environment it wouldnt have libreoffice, etc. Installed anyways and you could install exactly what you want.  If that cant happen, it might be a good idea to go for a different distro with a smaller footprint--there are lots made to cater to this situation

Comment: @Prime it looks like it's a ubuntu version for parallella. I can only find the image for this OS. http://elinux.org/Parallella_Software As an alternative I could also try installing debian or one of the other listed operating systems. But I'm still wondering how to tackle the problem above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just edit the image. You must recompile the binary in order to ensure that you have a bootable image.

Now, while there are a few tools you can use to modify the ubuntu distribution such as the [Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/), you might want to think about trying a different distribution to suit your needs.

If you like Ubuntu since you're familiar with it, [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) (for lower end devices) and [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) (light-weight Ubuntu alternative) will suit your needs on such a small device.

[Gentoo](https://gentoo.org) and [Debian](https://www.debian.org) (from which Ubuntu is a derivative) are great alternatives.

*Also*, you might want to take a look at this, it seems someone else has had a similar issue: [pubuntu](https://github.com/parallella/pubuntu) (ubuntu image for parallela).

Comment: NOTE: I've accepted this answer because, khaliq says it the image has to be recompiled. Unfortunately I haven't tried this out and accepted the answer based on intuition.